# java ms access connection

Tags: java, bluej, jdbc-odbc

I am using BlueJ to carry out some tasks is Java. I can not understand why I can't get any records from my MS Access database. Any help will be appreciated

```
import java.sql.*;

public class Database
{
    private Statement s;

    /**
     * Constructor for objects of class database
     */
    public database()
    {
        try{
            Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
        }catch(ClassNotFoundException exp){
            System.err.println(exp);
        }    
        try{
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:POS", "", "");
            this.s = con.createStatement();
        }catch(SQLException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }       
    }

    public void test(){
       try{
           this.s.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM product");
           ResultSet rset = s.getResultSet();
           System.out.println(rset.getString("title"));
       }catch(SQLException e){
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
    }
}
```

Here is the output I get when running test() function

> java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Invalid cursor
>   state     at
>   sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.createSQLException(JdbcOdbc.java:6956)     at
>   sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.standardError(JdbcOdbc.java:7113)  at
>   sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.SQLGetDataString(JdbcOdbc.java:3906)   at
>   sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcResultSet.getDataString(JdbcOdbcResultSet.java:5697)
>     at
>   sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcResultSet.getString(JdbcOdbcResultSet.java:353)
>     at
>   sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcResultSet.getString(JdbcOdbcResultSet.java:410)
>     at database.test(database.java:35)  at _*SHELL9.run(*_SHELL9.java:8)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)     at
>   bluej.runtime.ExecServer$3.run(ExecServer.java:725)

I have the ODBC driver set up and my database name is right. It is not password protected.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to move the cursor though the `ResultSet` with [next()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#next%28%29)

```
ResultSet rset = s.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM product");
if (rset.next()) {
   System.out.println(rset.getString("title"));
}
```

Comment: It depends on how many rows the OP is expecting to find I guess.

Comment: Yeah, that works great, thank you. I thought accessing resultSet without calling next() method will return the first record.

Answer (score 1):

A `ResultSet` is a set, so you have to `iterate` over it:

```
ResultSet rset = s.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM product");
while(rset.next()){
    System.out.println(rset.getString("title"));
}
```

P.S. don't forget to close the `ResultSet` and `Statement` when you are done with them.

Comment: Thanks, both your and Reimeus answers are correct but I choose his because returning only the first row was my original intention